# Pnorm (Cumulative Distribution Function of Normal Distribution) Underlying Formula Needed

Tags: r, pnorm, cumulative-distribution-function

In R, what is the underlying function that creates this output?

```
pnorm(0.079)
0.5314837
```

For context I want to determine what value `x` should be `pnorm(x)` so that the result is equal to `0.50`.

I can't do that unless I know the underlying formula

Comment: If you want the inverse of the `pnorm` function, use the `qnorm` function. For example `qnorm(.5)` return 0 because the normal distribution is symmetric about 0. See the `?pnorm` help page for more info. The explicit density is also given there as well.

Comment: that worked, thank you! Can you add this as an answer?